# Firmar XML de factura electrónica Paraguay

Tags: php, xml

Tengo este código en php con la librería xmlseclibs donde necesito firmar solo en nodo DE
aparte de firmar el nodo debe agregar 2 transformaciones.
El nodo de firma es el DE, ya que después de firmar necesito agregar mas detalles después de la firma.
También las transformaciones según el manual técnico solicita 2 la cual solo me aparece 1.

```
     $xml  = new DOMDocument();
     $file = 'files/' . $cdc . '.xml';
     $xml->load($file);
//echo $file;
//$variable = '#01800112994017003000026222023030211809049267';


$certificado = file_get_contents('cert.p12');
$contrasena  = 'passcert';

openssl_pkcs12_read($certificado, $clave, $contrasena);
$clave_privada        = $clave['pkey'];
$cadena_certificacion = $clave['cert'];

$objDSig = new RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityDSig('', array('prefix' => 'ds'));
$objDSig->setCanonicalMethod(RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityDSig::C14N);

$objDSig->addReference(
    $xml,
    RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityDSig::SHA256,
    array('http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature'),
    array('force_uri' => true, 'algorithm' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#')
);

//$objDSig->appendTransform($transform, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#');
//$objDSig->addTransform($transform);

$objKey = new RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityKey(RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA256, array('type' => 'private'));
$objKey->loadKey($clave_privada);
$objDSig->sign($objKey);

$objDSig->add509Cert($cadena_certificacion, true);
$objDSig->appendSignature($xml->documentElement);

$xmlString  = $xml->saveXML();
$firmados   = 'firmados/' . $cdc . '.xml';
file_put_contents($firmados, $xmlString  );
```

Comment: Muy buenas!, yo asigné una variable así: $DE = $documento->getElementsByTagName("DE")->item(0); me hace la firma pero me dice: > "Valor de la firma (SignatureValue) diferente del calculado por el PKI." lograste hacer la firma como estabas queriendo?

Answer (score 0):

La solución esta en agregar en el array de arTransforms ambas direcciones.

```
$objDSig->addReference(
    $xml,
    RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityDSig::SHA256,
    array('http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature'),
    array('force_uri' => true)
);
```